# Where does the "nuget pack project" command get the version info?

Tags: nuget-package

When I run the following command: nuget pack Security.Common.csproj, I got this result: Security.Common.0.1.0-origin-develop0005.nupkg

I don't know exactly where does this command get this version number: origin-develop0005. I see this version number in the dlls and AssemblyInfo.cs. If I change the version number in AssemblyInfo.cs, it still result the same file name. So it's getting from the dll?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't created Security.Common.nuspec file, then it will take the version number from ProductVersion field of VersionInfo resource of compiled DLL.